# Как сделать выпадающий блок?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Как сделать выпадающий блок по примеру на сайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/. Если навести на "медучереждения" увидите всплывающий темный блок.

Я делаю следующим образом:

```
<ul>
        <li> 
            <a href="#" class="menu_href">
                                    <img src="images/menu_icon_1.png"/></br>
                                    </br>
                                    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:14px;">МЕДУЧРЕЖДЕНИЯ</span><br>
                                    <span style="color:#9d9d9d; font-size:12px;">адреса, отзывы</span>

                                </a>
        </li>
....... и т д
```

Ниже блок которые выезжает.

```
<div class="menu_vipad_1">

                <ul class="category">
                    <li>
                        <ul class="subcategory">
                            <li><a href="#">Больницы и стационары</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Поликлиники</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Диспансеры</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Медпункты и амбулатории</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Травмпункты</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Скорая помощь</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Частные медцентры и клиники</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Стоматология</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Центры вакцинации</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

И jqeury

```
$('.menu_href').hover(function(){
        $('.menu_vipad_1').show(200);

        },

        function(){

           $('.menu_vipad_1').hide(); 

        });
```

т.е. блок выпадает, но только когда я навожу на него мышкой, он исчезает. Как сделать чтобы он оставался при наведении, и исчезал, например, при клике на другое место или при наведении на другое меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем? Можно же на `css`:

```
.menu_vipad_1 { opacity:0; -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;-moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;-ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in;-o-transition: all 100ms ease-in;transition: all 100ms ease-in;}
```

и событие:

```
a:hover + .menu_vipad_1 {opacity:1}
```

Что бы блок не исчезал, нужно .menu_vipad_1 поместить в ссылку, или с помощью jquery добавить класс или через data-* атрибут.

Comment: А через Jquery нельзя?? Вот ссылку сделал http://jsfiddle.net/6434fguL/

Comment: @duddeniska зачем грузить страницу js? я показал Вам код, аналогичный Вашему. Если с помощью добавления классов – тогда уже js нужен, а так можно решить проблему гораздо проще.На фидле ничего не работает (Хром)

Comment: Да я первый раз запустли фидл

Comment: @duddeniska в любом случаи я предложил Вам решение попроще :) юзать или нет – уже ваши вопросы

Comment: @ ka5itoshka К сожалению не работает((((

Comment: @duddeniska если поместили .menu_vipad_1 в a, то логично что нужно и css изменить на a:hover > .menu_vipad_1 {opacity:1}